# Responses page takes a long time to load

Tags: bug

In the last couple of weeks or so, it takes a long time for the page to display when I click on "responses" in my EE.SE main site profile.

At first I thought this was something on my machine, or something temporary SE was going to fix.  But it's been two weeks or so and it's still the same.  I timed it, and it takes 17-20 seconds.  This is from clicking "responses" to seeing the page content, and also just when refreshing the page when already there.  This happens on a Win7 system running Internet Explorer, and on a WinXP system running Chrome.

The weird thing is this only happens on EE.SE, and only on the main site.  I have no problem on Engineering.SE, Photography, and a few others.

Is this a bug, "feature", or is there something I can do?

### Update

It seems to be working again.  Thanks for fixing this.

Comment: Interestingly, I can reproduce this on my end - it took 19 seconds to load it (forcing a full refresh). I'll see if I can get an answer.

Comment: @W5VO: Thanks.  I thought it might be just my account for some reason, like I reached some number of responses that the software treats differently.  It's good to see independent confirmation.

Comment: You've overloaded the database! The lights over here dim every time you do that ...  :-)

Comment: I also reproduced (~17 seconds in a SQL query). I'll check with a dev.